# How to gzip response while using Bottle with Cherrypy?

Tags: python, compression, gzip, cherrypy, bottle

I would like to do the above stated at the application level and not for individual requests.An alternative one time solution/ setting in config file to make this a default setting for the server would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use `tools.gzip.on: True` on cherrypy config file.
See this [link](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#per-application-configuration)

Also Instead if you can use uwsgi, you can add this to your config:

```
route-if = contains:${HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING};gzip goto:mygzipper
route-run = last:

route-label = mygzipper
; pass the response to the gzip transformation
route = .* delheader:Content-Length
route = .* gzip:
```